Getting the Manifest for CNAB - BLOB_UNKNOWN error
I am using this C# sample https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/containers.containerregistry-readme?view=azure-dotnet to download the config blob. This works ok if I use a docker image, but I need to download a CNAB bundle from ACR.
Here is how the image index/manifest looks for the sample CNAB in ACR
{
  "schemaVersion": 2,
  "manifests": [
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json",
      "digest": "sha256:870ac3b87f7ebadedba4ad57726a8ad3d6cdabbe4c8a44a28b88b02b84c33f21",
      "size": 189,
      "annotations": {
        "io.cnab.manifest.type": "config"
      }
    },
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "digest": "sha256:d87908ebea59344443e8431575f4ff7622f78490df569fd082b14e33754c1a21",
      "size": 2413,
      "annotations": {
        "io.cnab.manifest.type": "invocation"
      }
    },
    {
      "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
      "digest": "sha256:afb0bc2804dabef9c7b410b7345c6adb5f419b6a5f44b727c3275c6f58c1a229",
      "size": 3257,
      "annotations": {
        "io.cnab.component.name": "websvc",
        "io.cnab.manifest.type": "component"
      }
    }
  ],
  "annotations": {
    "io.cnab.runtime_version": "1.2.0",
    "org.opencontainers.artifactType": "application/vnd.cnab.manifest.v1",
    "org.opencontainers.image.description": "cnab demo",
    "org.opencontainers.image.title": "cnabdemo",
    "org.opencontainers.image.version": "0.1.0"
  }
}

I am able to download the image index/manifest of CNAB (the above json) successfully which has a mediatype of application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json, however going through the manifest, when I try to download the config file with mediatype application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json  (the first manifest in the json), I always get BLOB_UNKNOWN error. Is this because C# SDK doesn't recognize this mediatype (while it works ok for the image index) or an access restriction?
Appreciate any inputs.

Where is the error occurring?  Data get downloaded and then deserialized.  Not sure why is failing.  Do you have a viewer for the media type that fails?
